# Excel 2007 opens with only one worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

In Excel 2007, when User A creates a new workbook, there is only 1 worksheet for the book. When user B creates a new workbook, there is the standard 3 worksheets for the book. How do I get this back to default for User A?

The workbook being opened has more than 50 worksheets that have been in the file for the last year. When User B opens the file, all 50 or more sheets are accessible. This happens with both files saved as 2003 files because the workbook has VBA macros in it and if I open new xlsx files that are in Excel 2007 format.

Cancel the question.  This was apparently a cockpit error. the workbook was sized very large when a space delimited (.prn) version of one worksheet was made.  I would swear I checked this before I asked the question,  but I just reduced the workbook size again and the problem went away.  It is interesting that the problem migrated to all excel files for user A.

Comment: What? You have one user that opens workbooks with 3 sheets and another user that opens workbooks with 1 sheet?

Comment: NO.  the workbook already exists with 50 or more worksheets in it all with data in them. You oversimplifed the question.

Comment: @Raystafarian Please be more subtle with those edits. You removed possibly important information and left nothing of the original question. Just rewrite a post to fix grammar and correct obvious mistakes, and respect the original author. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

That's a per-user setting, with the default 3. To change it in Excel 2007, go to `Microsoft excel button (multi colored top left icon, aka "pearl") -> excel options button (bottom right) -> popular tab.` in the "when creating new workbooks" section change `include this many sheets` to your desired number of sheets.

Answer (score 1):

And in Excel 2010 change it as follows:

Click on green `File` tab then `Options`. In the `General` section find `When creating new workbooks`. Set `Include this many sheets` to the number of worksheets you want.

Answer (score 0):

And in Excel 2016 we've seen a quirky issue when Excel initially opens with the "Show the Start screen when this application starts" setting selected, it doesn't actually show the Excel Start screen (not sure why but may) but opens a workbook with a single worksheet ***REGARDLESS*** of the user setting for "Include this many sheets" (opening subsequent new workbooks uses this setting as expected).

Turning the "Start screen" option **OFF** makes Excel work as expected.